# Increasing height constraint, stretching "Runtime added subviews"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

The line mentioned with *comments is stretching the subviews that are not bound with any constraint to its parent view.

```
NSMutableArray* tagItemLabels=[NSMutableArray new];
    NSMutableArray* data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"One",@"One Hundred",@"One Hundred Eleven",@"Thousand One Hundered",@"two",@"Three", nil];

    for (NSString* title in data) {

        MSTag * tagItem=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MSTag" owner:self options:kNilOptions] objectAtIndex:0];
        [tagItem.lblTitle setText:title];
        [self.tagView addSubview:tagItem];

        CGRect frame = tagItem.frame;
        //frame.size.height=30;

        CGSize expectedLabelSize = [title sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]}];

        if (tagItemLabels.count<=0) {
            frame.origin.x=8;
            frame.origin.y=8;
            frame.size.width=expectedLabelSize.width+70;
            frame.size.height=30;
        }else{
            frame=((UIView*)([tagItemLabels lastObject])).frame;
            frame.origin.x+=frame.size.width+12;
            frame.size.height=30;
            frame.size.width=expectedLabelSize.width+70;
            NSLog(@"%f==%f",frame.origin.x+tagItem.frame.size.width+12,self.tagView.frame.size.width);

            if (frame.origin.x+frame.size.width>self.tagView.frame.size.width) {
                //if (frame.origin.x+frame.size.width>self.TagView.frame.size.width) {
                frame.origin.x=8;
                frame.origin.y+=frame.size.height+8;
            }
        }

        //***If I write this line my views get streched!***//
        self.constraintTagViewHeight.constant=frame.origin.y+frame.size.height;

        [tagItem setFrame:frame];
        [tagItemLabels addObject:tagItem];
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? It is not obvious what you are asking here...Do you want the pink view to be as big so that all labels are inside it (a bit more than Three label)?

Comment: yes the pink one is parent view of all these tagViews. I have to add other parent views below the pick one and these all parent views will be in scroll view. First I tried doing this whole thing using tableView and create different prototype cells and put the row height automatic dimention. But, same happens in cell as well, increasing the constraint of item in cell should increase cell height, after calling begin and end updating cell of table view. but it also increasing tag heights. title and cross btn are center align in tags no top and down constraint attach to it.

Comment: Try adding `tagItem.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone` below `MSTag * tagItem=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MSTag" owner:self options:kNilOptions] objectAtIndex:0];` It looks like XIB file has autoresizing mask to flexible height, so when superview's height changes so to will the tags height

Comment: Yes it work as it should, Why didin't you answer it separately, I want to mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: I will right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like XIB file has autoresizing mask set to flexible height, and thus its height changes when superview's height changes, just add

`tagItem.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone`

below

`MSTag * tagItem=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MSTag" owner:self options:kNilOptions] objectAtIndex:0];`

this will set the correct autoresizing mask and tags will not grow in height when superview's height changes